# jquery load cache

Tags: jquery

I Have a jquery click event which loads a html form into a div using .load()

the form snippet has a reference js file which redefines the js while also populating the form inputs with ajax responses.

when i click save on the form the div is then loaded (using .load) a view version of what was saved.

If I click on edit again to instigate the first action I mentioned, the load is executed but the javascript reference is not reloaded so the ajax population doesnt kick in

Any solutions?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controls.js"></script>
```

EDIT: adding code

```
function populate() {
        var index = 1;
        $("#list").html("&nbsp;");
        for (item in object) {
            var html ='blah';
            $("#list").append(html);

            $(".item").live('click',
                function() {
                    $("#container").load("./html-includes/file.html?ver="+ver, function () {
                        apiCall.getData(referenceId);
                        alert('callback'+$rootScope.currentPage);
                    });
                }
            );
            index++;
        };
    }
```

in this case file html has the javascript reference previously mentioned which has a debug alert in it which isnt filring on the second call to the .load

Comment: Without seeing any code or anything I am making a guess that you need to look at jQuery's on() method - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: What does that have to do with caching?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your $.load() method works first time because browser doesn't have data in cache. Next time when you call it in loop Ajax call is not performed but data returned from cache. As result callback is not fired....
You can see this using fidller or similar tool - you will see only one request to the server....

Possible solution is to turn off caching (see $.ajax() method) or add dynamic parameters in the query (aka url) like current time, so browser will not cache result.
Or use post method in $.load() (just add any data to send and Jquery will use post instead of get), though I am not sure if it is elegant way to do this -).